# mock global object in method namespace

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

Is it possible to mock a global object, such as an imported module, in a specific method from a different module?

Example:

```
import some_module

class MyClass():
    def a_method(self):
        some_module.do_something(1)
    def b_method(self):
        some_module.do_something(2)
```

I would like to patch `some_module` so as to set the return value of `do_somthing()`, but only in `a_method()` and not in `b_method()`. Of course I could use a decorator, however I would like to patch from a different module.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot patch out `some_module.do_something()` limited to `MyClass().a_method()`, no.

You'd normally be selective *in time* when to patch instead. Apply the patch only when `MyClass().a_method()` is being called and make sure the patch is undone again before `MyClass().b_method()` is called.

A good unittest already ensures that you test *just* `a_method()` *anyway*. If `a_method()` is not under test but used by other code that *is*, then patch out `a_method()` directly.